# Where can I find the reason why TDE encryption Scan aborted?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transparent-data-encryption

When encrypting large database > 10TB . I had to issue --alter database  set encryption on several times , but the encryption starts and fails with the same message in the error log. where can i find why the encryption scan failed ?

Error Log entry

> Database encryption scan for database  was aborted. Reissue
>   ALTER DB to resume the scan. This is message in the sql server error
>   log.

The  Database compatibility level is `130`

To be clear when I run the `alter db <dbname> set encryption on` command the encryption starts progresses by small percent and fails immediately. currently it is at `0.4716863` percent . when it fails it fails with `encryption_state = 2 and percent_complete=0`

SQL Server version

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7-GDR) (KB4505222) - 13.0.5366.0 (X64) Jun 15 2019 08:22:25 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the message in the error log?

Comment: Database encryption scan for database <DBNAME> was aborted. Reissue ALTER DB to resume the scan. This is message in the sql server error log.

Comment: what is the db compat level ?

Comment: The compat level is it is on 130

Comment: what does `sys.dm_database_encryption_keys` --> what is the encryption_state. can you run `ALTER DATABASE <name> SET ENCRYPTION ON` ?

Comment: To be clear when I run the alter db <dbname> set encryption on command the encryption starts progresses by small percent and fails immediately. currently it is at 0.4716863 percent . when it fails it fails with encryption_state = 2 and percent_complete=0

Comment: Interesting. What version an build and edition you are running sql server on ?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU7-GDR) (KB4505222) - 13.0.5366.0 (X64)   Jun 15 2019 08:22:25   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Enterprise Edition: Core-based Licensing (64-bit) on Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard 6.3 <X64> (Build 9600: )

Comment: @yegnasew - I'm not sure if this solution helps - [SQL Server 2016 TDE: Database encryption scan for 'DB_name' was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45604784)

Comment: @yegnasew - you said that `when it fails it fails with encryption_state = 2 and percent_complete=0`  but `encryption_state =2` ==> in progress .. Am I missing something ? what is `encryption_scan_state_desc` ?

Comment: There is a [FIX: Encryption scan task triggered upon the startup of a database may be canceled in SQL Server 2016](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4466107/fix-encryption-scan-task-triggered-upon-the-startup-of-a-database-may)  for a different TDE issue in **SP2 CU8**. It does not seem to apply to you but might be worh it to keep in mind.

Comment: @KinShah Encryption in progress is the state description.

Comment: It will take time to encrypt 10TB of database. As long as it is in progress, I would not kill or abort it. let it finish.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Thank you, if I cant continue any other way . I will try that. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: what ever happened with this? did you post the actual error message and I'm just not seeing it?

Comment: I have the same problem here for SQL Server 2017 Developer Edition: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/328504/transparent-data-encryption-doesnt-appear-to-start-encrypting-the-db . I don't think the encryption is in progress. The log file says it has aborted the encryption and I always get tired of waiting for hours for it to finish. And I am pretty much clueless on why it aborts the process, since the log says too little of any value.